# VS 2019 keeps asking for re-entering my credentials for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, devops

Every time I log in I connect to DevOps through Visual Studio Pro 2019. It asks for entering the credentials. Is there a way to save them and connect them to the DevOps server directly?

Comment: Could you try logging in Visual Studio Pro 2019 with the same credentials for Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could possibly be the "Cryptographic network provider" and "Credential helper" in the "Git Global Settings". Check to see if they are Unset and if so set them to OpenSSL and GCM Core respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I my case I had a Nuget source for a package inside Azure DevOps, ex:

```
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/...
```

And the credentials were no longer working, showing this error in the output window:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"User 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi.FeedNeedsPermissionsException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi",
            "typeKey":"FeedNeedsPermissionsException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation was similar to @gharel I had a private Nuget source in the NuGet.Config file that I didn't have credentials set for.

Added the credentials, restarted visual studio, and it worked fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="{yourPrivateSource}" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/{yourPrivateSource}/index.json" />
    
    </packageSources>

    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <{yourPrivateSource}>
            <add key="Username" value="{yourUsername}" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{yourPassword}" />
        </{yourPrivateSource}>      
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System web browser` under `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts`

More info [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/work-with-multi-factor-authentication?view=vs-2019)